# linux установить и настроить postgresql поверх/паралельно с системной postgresql

Tags: linux, база-данных, postgresql, установка

В системе стоит postgres 9.6

В отдельный каталог установил последнюю 12.3 по инструкции https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/install-short.html и в `./configure` строку добавил `--prefix=PREFIX` , т.е. `./configure --prefix=/sharefolder/postgre-12.3`

но затем начали появляться ошибки, например:

```
postgres@astra:~$ psql test
psql: не удалось подключиться к серверу: Нет такого файла или каталога
        Он действительно работает локально и принимает
        соединения через Unix-сокет "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

ведь ничего не должно быть в `/var/run/postgresql/` для 12.3 ...

и еще не то выдает, что нужно, от системной постгре дает

```
$ pg_lsclusters
Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory               Log file
9.6 main    5432 down   postgres /var/lib/postgresql/9.6/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.6-main.log

$ psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 9.6.15
```

как мне нормально настроить 12.3 поверх установленной системной?

PS: и как *pgadmin* поставить с исходников также в ту отдельную папку /sharefolder/ или без него можно, если webstorm и intellij есть?

Comment: Путь к unix-сокетам для сервера устанавливается через unix_socket_directories в postgresql.conf, а для клиента - через -h или в ~/.psqlrc

Comment: И по поводу "не то даёт": запускаете команды без явного пути. Те из двух установленных комплектов, которые в PATH первые, те и выполняются.

Comment: Поставь pg из пакета... Самые свежие версии есть на оф сайте и на постреспро

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev не знаю точно как путь к unix-сокетам для сервера поставить, подскажете? (только начинаю в Линуксе..)

Comment: @CodeGust подскажу: читать [документацию](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/12/index), точнее, [главу про настройку](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/12/runtime-config), еще точнее [на предмет параметра unix_socket_directories](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/12/runtime-config-connection). Это не только линукса касается, BTW.

Comment: но вообще в случае тольконачинающего рекомендую прислушаться к комментарию @eri, а не пытаться лезть в дебри (ради чего, кстати?)

Comment: https://entnet-ru.turbopages.org/turbo/entnet.ru/s/special/1s-predpriyatie/server-1s-i-pg.html Может по аналогии как тут попробовать

Answer (score 3):

Есть такая полезная штука -- docker / docker-compose.
Ей можно любые сервера ставить, в сети объединять и т. п.

Answer (score 2):

Есть такая полезная штука [asdf](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf). Позволяет устанавливать и управлять версиями в том числе и [postgres](https://github.com/smashedtoatoms/asdf-postgres).

На примере postgres поясню, что asdf дает. Он позволяет:

1. установить несколько версий независимо от системной. Каждая версия устанавливается в отдельный католог. Причем это одной простой командой типа `asdf install postgres 12.3`.
2. выбрать из установленных версий ту которая будет использоваться. Можно опеределить отдельно глобальную, отдельно - локальную для папки или для текущей сессии. asdf это делает путем изменения `PATH`. Установака для текущей сессии выглядит так: `asdf shell postgres 12.3`

А вообще поддерживается очень [много](https://asdf-vm.com/#/plugins-all) софта. Это унифицированный аналог таких полезных вещей как sdkman, nvm и pyenv

Comment: спасибо, попробовал, поставил, но все то же самое.
$ psql test
psql: не удалось подключиться к серверу: Нет такого файла или каталога
        Он действительно работает локально и принимает
        соединения через Unix-сокет "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

Answer (score 2):

Установите из пакета по инструкции https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt